# How can solve error in autopytoexe to compile python program to exe?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

when I try to compile program in python 3.7 
with:

1. auto-py-to-exe v2.6.0
2. Selenium

The code is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pathlib
import resource

fn = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'chromedriver.exe'


browser = webdriver.Chrome(fn)
browser.get('website')

# fill in username and hit the next button
username = browser.find_element_by_id('user_login')
username.send_keys('xxxxxxx')

password = browser.find_element_by_id('user_pass')
password.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxx')

nextButton1 = browser.find_element_by_id('wp-submit')
nextButton1.click()

browser.get('website')

nextButton2 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('add-new-h2')
nextButton2.click()

nextButton3 = browser.find_element_by_id('is_continue_no')
nextButton3.click()

nextButton4 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('rad10')
nextButton4.click()
```

error in compile

```
An error occurred, traceback follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\documentos\proyectos\synctango2woocomerce\venv\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe-2.6.0-py3.7.egg\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 259, in convert
    pyi.run() # Execute PyInstaller
  File "e:\documentos\proyectos\synctango2woocomerce\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "e:\documentos\proyectos\synctango2woocomerce\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "e:\documentos\proyectos\synctango2woocomerce\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "e:\documentos\proyectos\synctango2woocomerce\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
  File "e:\documentos\proyectos\synctango2woocomerce\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 424, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "e:\documentos\proyectos\synctango2woocomerce\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 196, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "e:\documentos\proyectos\synctango2woocomerce\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "e:\documentos\proyectos\synctango2woocomerce\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 273, in assemble
    pylib_name = os.path.basename(bindepend.get_python_library_path())
  File "C:\Users\Jesus-NewPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 214, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "C:\Users\Jesus-NewPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

[all log](https://pastebin.com/xHm36s4u)

i expect correct compile

i try

1. install windows sdk
2. install visual c++ libraries

need help to resolve the problem
this is the code from my python program

Comment: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType` How is this question related to _Selenium_ or _selenium-webdriver_ ? Am I missing something?

Comment: you're right i edited the post the question has more to do with pyinstaller because it tries to compile, although the program uses selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in the simplest way, pass the proyect folder with the script to
  disk C: and the errors were solved gave error while it was saved in disk E:

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that you are trying to load `chromedriver.exe` which can be found in your current directory but after freezing it cannot be loaded anymore. When you want to freeze your app with Pyinstaller you first need to add that file to your output executable and then load it from the temp directory.

I'm not sure about `auto-py-to-exe` but you can use the below code and then use

`pyinstaller -F --add-data "chromedriver.exe;." yourscript.py`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import resource
import sys
import os


def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)

fn = resource_path('chromedriver.exe')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(fn)
browser.get('website')

# fill in username and hit the next button
username = browser.find_element_by_id('user_login')
username.send_keys('xxxxxxx')

password = browser.find_element_by_id('user_pass')
password.send_keys('xxxxxxxxxx')

nextButton1 = browser.find_element_by_id('wp-submit')
nextButton1.click()

browser.get('website')

nextButton2 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('add-new-h2')
nextButton2.click()

nextButton3 = browser.find_element_by_id('is_continue_no')
nextButton3.click()

nextButton4 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('rad10')
nextButton4.click()
```

Comment: First, uninstall pyinstaller completely with `pip uninstall pyinstaller` then delete `C:/Users/<Username>/AppData/Roaming/Pyinstaller` directory. Next Install pyinstaller with `pip install -U pyinstaller`.

Comment: If still doesn't work try to replace [bindepend.py](https://github.com/Loran425/pyinstaller/blob/14b6e65642e4b07a4358bab278019a48dedf7460/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py) in `<Python path>\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend` directory.

Comment: Your problem is that your Pyinstaller is broken. Try to use pure **Pyinstaller** not the `auto-py-to-exe`.